# How can I import certification file by path in Google app engine (in python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

experts, I want to built a automatic trading program in google app engine. How can I import my certification?
I have try to put it in root folder/ in storage/ and read it from storage and yield a new file in tmp folder, however, it did not work, either reply "read-only system" or "file can not found".
Can anybody show me how to import file (by path) in Google app engine?

THX

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python3.7, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import files in Google App Engine using Python, you can put the file in a bucket in Cloud Storage and read the file from there. You may take the reference of this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) which talks in detail on how you can specify the bucket and read the file from there-in.

You may also have a look at the code sample present in the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087895/how-to-open-a-file-in-google-app-engine-using-python-3-5).

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, I can read the file from bucket in Cloud Storage, but that's not what I want, I need to import a path of certification file (.pfx). What should I do? Where can I get file path?

Comment: You may have a look at these [Install SSl certificate on GAE](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/install-ssl-certificate-on-google-app-engine) and the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_ssl_certificate). Let me know if that helps!