# Getting "encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" On Installing pyautogui via PIP

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pyautogui

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to install "pyautogui" library to python. Please find the details below -

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "################\pip-install-pmckiy\pygetwindow\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
with open('README.md', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\################\pip-install-pmckiy\pygetwindow\
```

`Python Version - 2.7.12`

Things I have already tried -

1.) I have upgraded the pip, current version - pip 19.1.1

2.) I also followed the steps as given in this another answer

["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

3.) Since this is installation I have no control over the code, also I tried to search for this error in the files but no luck, hence below URL also did not help me much -

[Is 'encoding is an invalid keyword' error inevitable in python 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049962/is-encoding-is-an-invalid-keyword-error-inevitable-in-python-2-x)

4.) I tried installing setuptools as well but it is also not helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in pygetwindow, already reported but not resolved: https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/issues/9

The problem is that in Python 3 [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) has parameter `encoding`, but [not in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open). That is, the code now requires Python 3.