# Getting this error message "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'" while webscraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to webscrape the Bon appetit website for title and ingredients but have gotten completely stuck on the above error message. I feel like maybe I'm scraping the wrong html elements but these are the only ones that make sense. Please let me know if you have helpful tips!

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_scrape = "https://www.bonappetit.com/recipes"
request_page = urlopen(url_to_scrape)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
recipes = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="card-body")

filename = 'recipes.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')
headers = 'title, ingredients \n'
f.write(headers)

for recipe in recipes:
    title = recipe.find('div', class_='card-hed')
    ingredients = recipe.find('div', class_='card-copy')
    
    f.write(title + ',' + ingredients)
    f.close
```

Comment: `title` is `None` and you are adding it to a string `','`.

Comment: @count-integral is there anyway to change that?

Comment: Well of course you can get rid of the error, but what are you trying to achieve? What were you expecting `title`'s value to be?

Comment: ideally, a string with the title of the recipe

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong tag to get the values. The `title` and `ingredients` are present under `h1` and `p` tags respectively but you were looking at incorrect tags to get the values.

Try this working code:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_scrape = "https://www.bonappetit.com/recipes"
request_page = urlopen(url_to_scrape)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
recipes = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="card-body")

filename = 'recipes.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')
headers = 'title, ingredients \n'
f.write(headers)

for recipe in recipes:
    #print(recipe)

    title = recipe.find('h1', class_='card-hed').text
    ingredients = recipe.find('p', class_='card-copy').text
    f.write(title + ',' + ingredients)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm now getting this error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 25, in <module>
    f.write(title + ',' + ingredients)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 83: ordinal not in range(128), any clues?

Comment: please try with `f.write(str(title) + ',' + str(ingredients))`

Comment: @alwaystuck Maybe using UTF-8 will help `open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I still seem to be getting this error message. Do you mind telling me if you think this approach is correct or should I try using selenium?

Comment: @counter-integral, I get this error when I try that: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: looks like you are running the script with python2, try with the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541370/typeerror-encoding-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-function

Comment: I tried that and recieved this error message:       'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1342, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

Comment: @alwaystuck You do not show what the exception is (in your comment), just where it happened.